# ¿Cómo enviar un archivo por websockets a php?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

Soy nuevo en este tema y estoy tratando de mandar un archivo por medio de websockets desde JavaScript a php usando este código en el script:

```
<script>

 var wsUri = "ws://127.0.0.1:9000/server_msg.php";
 websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

 var message = $("#file")[0].files[0];

...

 var msg = {
  type: type_select,
  type_msg: type_msg,
  id_msg_incoming: id_incoming,
  id_msg_outgoing: id_msg_outgoing,
  message: message, //esta variable es la que contiene la imagen
 };
 websocket.binaryType = "blob";//Supuestamente esto es para "asignar" el tipo de dato
 websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

</script>
```

Lamentablemente no funciona, solo puedo pasar texto y los datos de la imagen llegan vacíos.

*Archivo server_msg.php que encontre para "desempaquetar" la información:*

```
while (socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
 $received = unmask($buf); //"desempaquetado" de datos
 $data = json_decode($received, true);
}

function unmask($text) //"desempaquetado" del mensaje
{
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if ($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    } elseif ($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    } else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i % 4];
    }
    return $text;
}
```

*Respuesta de la consola en donde ejecuto el archivo php del servidor websocket:*

```
Array
(
    [type] => chat
    [type_msg] => image
    [id_msg_incoming] => 93
    [id_msg_outgoing] => 111
    [message] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Estuve investigando y se supone que tengo que convertirlo a binario; ya lo hice, pero el servidor por alguna razón no reconoce el archivo enviado.

agradecería mucho su ayuda, de antemano, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 3):

La expresión de JavaScript `$("#file")[0].files[0]` retorna un objeto tipo `File`, el cual no se serializa correctamente con `JSON.stringify`, como se indica en este ejemplo.

```js
window.myfile.onchange = function (e) {
  window.json.value = JSON.stringify({ file: this.files[0] });
};
```

```html
<input id="myfile" type="file">
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="json" rows="10" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
```

Para serializar el objeto es recomendable codificar su contenido en [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), y decodificarlo del lado del servidor con la función [`base64_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-decode.php). La codificación del lado del cliente puede hacerse así:

```js
window.myfile.onchange = function (e) {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function (e) {
    var base64URL = this.result;
    var base64Mark = ';base64,';
    var base64MarkIndex = base64URL.indexOf(base64Mark);
    var base64Data = base64MarkIndex !== -1 ? base64URL.substring(base64MarkIndex + base64Mark.length) : "";
    window.json.value = JSON.stringify({ file: base64Data });
  };
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

```html
<input id="myfile" type="file">
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="json" rows="10" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
```